# Facebook Javascript oAuth Error Occurrred

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

atm i m trying to get the facebook api to work, i stuck at the oauth

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" onlogin="OnRequestPermission();">
</fb:login-button>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: '143655195699763',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As far as i try to login i get a error

> An error occurred. Please try again later.

Any idea?

Also if i use that one, i still get the same error message ... maybe it have something todo with my appID?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '395527397147712', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };
</script>
<script>
 function fb_publish() {
     FB.ui(
       {
         method: 'stream.publish',
         message: 'Message here.',
         attachment: {
           name: 'Name here',
           caption: 'Caption here.',
           description: (
             'description here'
           ),
           href: 'url here'
         },
         action_links: [
           { text: 'Code', href: 'action url here' }
         ],
         user_prompt_message: 'Personal message here'
       },
       function(response) {
         if (response && response.post_id) {
           alert('Post was published.');
         } else {
           alert('Post was not published.');
         }
       }
     );  
  }

</script>

<input name="" type="button" onClick="fb_publish()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats the only code you have? Have you readed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)?

Comment: updated first post with new code

Comment: Do you see anything in the console of your browser? FB writes more info about the error there maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause, but in the SDK Docs examples you have two functions one is fb.init (you have it) and the other one is an anonymous function that calls itself to load the script that you are attaching directly to the DOM, maybe you should load the script via the anonymous function; the code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Alos, make sure to hide properly the `#fb-root` element because in IE the SDK can cause issues. [More info here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)